# Is there a way to check if the nth radio button is selected in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to check if the nth radio button is selected in jQuery?  I'm looking to loop through a group of radio buttons and use the nth value in another area.  I'd prefer to not have to use :first :second etc.

Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: I was considering looping through the elements and then saving which one was checked for the first element.  Then taking that nth value and looping to that radio button in the next element to see if it was checked until the end of the list.  If all elements were checked as ON then I would use that value.  I was hoping there as a better way.

Comment: Post a [mcve] showing what you're working with and what you've tried please

Comment: Your comment makes this to a complete other question. Maybe you should edit your question and post some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes like so:

`$("#myRadio").is(":checked")`

for a collection:

```
$("#myRadioGroup input:radio").each(function(index, element) {
    console.log(element.checked);
});
```

Comment: `$(element).is(":checked")` is a really long-winded way to write `element.checked`...

Answer (score 1):

No need to loop:

```
const index = 5
$(':radio:nth(' + index + ')').is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking to loop through a group of radio buttons and use the nth value in another area

If you really want the loop, then:

```
$("selector-for-the-radio-buttons").each(function() {
    // Use `this.checked` here
});
```

If you just want the `nth` one:

```
$("selector-for-the-radio-buttons")[n].checked
```

or

```
$("selector-for-the-radio-buttons:eq(" + n + ")")[0].checked
// or if it may not exist, this will give you undefined instead of an error:
$("selector-for-the-radio-buttons:eq(" + n + ")").prop("checked")
// as will this:
$("selector-for-the-radio-buttons:eq(" + n + ").is(":checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an actual nth style you could use the `nth-of-type` method, like this

```
$('input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(<whatever-n>)').is(':checked')
```

Comment: `:checked`, not `selected`.

Comment: `:checked`, not `checked`.

Comment: What part is the selector if I have a class of myClass?

Comment: @Dale you could do something like `$(.myClass[type="radio"]...`